# How to import .scala file into eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala

I have an existing .scala file I played around with in Emacs, and would like to export it to Eclipse.  My first thought: import>Existing Projects into Workspace>*_*.scala doesn't work.  Is there an easy solution I'm overlooking?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to import a single source file or entire project?

Comment: If it's a single file why not to copy it into the working directory?

Comment: Do you mean a simple copy/paste?

Comment: Yes, or you want to edit it from different editors it one project?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a Scala project first with the [Scala plugin](http://scala-ide.com), specifying the directory of the .scala file as existing source. See [this guide](http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/gettingstarted/index.html).

Comment: Or alternatively, after creating the Scala project in another location, copy the file to the correct source folder.

Comment: Right, exporting scala projects from SBT is well defined with the eclipsify tool; information for that is readily available online and I would have been easily able to find out about it.  I'm talking about exporting a single .scala file into eclipse for editing